# specify the regex dot `.` and `..` in powershell to find files/directories?

Tags: powershell, regex

I find powershell in some ways, can do regexes to a limited extent. No doubt it can do more but I can't see why it isn't here.  I'm trying to use a regex to specify files/directories.

For example, when I have a directory called 'qwe' this will show it

```
PS C:\Users\bob\a> Get-ChildItem C:\Users\bob\a\[qwe][qwe][qwe]

d----        24/08/2014   1:28 PM            qwe
```

But I can't do

```
PS C:\Users\bob\a> Get-ChildItem C:\Users\bob\a\q.e
```

(to pick up the qwe directory)

And if I do

```
PS C:\Users\bob\a> Get-ChildItem C:\Users\bob\a\..
```

Then it goes back a directory and there's no way I can find to make it match a file/dir of 2+ characters or even 2 characters, with the regex `..`

However, it does support this aspect of regular expressions [abcd]  (a character class to match an 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd') or [a-z]  though it is somewhat unregex like as  [abcd] only matches where the result is one character.  With a proper regex it'd normally match anything with that character including when there's more than that character there.

Comment: These `[qwe]` are not regular expressions. This is part of globbing syntax (though results are same as in regular expressions). In globbing a way to specify 'any single character' is `?`. Try: `Get-ChildItem c:\users\bob\a\q?e` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot has a special meaning for file names, so you have to use Where-Object (or its short form) for such type of filtering:

```
Get-ChildItem . | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^q.e$' }
```

Comment: testing that on the machine i'm currently on.  `Get-ChildItem .` returns the directory, ok.  But  `Get-ChildItem . | Where-Object { $_Name -match 'a' }`  or  even `Get-ChildItem . | Where-Object { $_Name -match '.' }` (which should return everything 'cos any file/dir is at least one character.. but it returns nothing. Any time there's a | Where-Object......  after it I get nothing returned

Comment: example- http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kq757JUA

Comment: You've missed a '.' (dot) between $_ and Name.